# Why is there a difference in these translations of 'Grace', 'Power' and 'Precision' for my taekwondo belts?

Tags: vocabulary, translation

I am a martial artist, and for years I have had what I thought were the Korean symbols for Grace, Power and Precision put on my belts. Recently, our Grandmaster (Native born Korean) did me the honor of doing this in calligraphy, and I noticed that my older belt does not match my current belt, which does not match the calligraphy.

Is there an explanation for this, and do my belts not say what I think they do?

Calligraphy

[image]

Old belt

[image]

New Belt

[image]

Comment: Are these taekwondo belts?

Comment: @topomorto - Yes, the older one is my 4th degree belt and the newer one is my 5th degree.

Comment: Why do you think they have to match in the first place?

Comment: @Rathony - Obviously, I don't know anything about Korean language.

Comment: @Rathony - I should amend that. I know basic counting and terminology. But knowing how to say sparring in Korean is not the same thing as being able to read/write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first picture contains these 3 words written in Hanja (Chinese characters, which were traditionally used to write Korean and are still used sometimes for style) and the second and third are written in the Hangeul script.  The calligraphy writes the 3 words in a different order than the belts, and the two belts use different Korean words to translate these concepts:

First picture:

> 正確 = 정확 = precision
>
> 優雅 = 우아 = grace, elegance
>
> 力 = 력 (역) (not usually used by itself, except in Hanja form) = power

Second picture:

> 품위 = dignity, grace
>
> 힘 = strength, power
>
> 명확 = clearness, precision

Third picture:

> 은혜 = grace
>
> 힘 =  strength, power
>
> 정밀 = precision, accuracy

Comment: 명확 is closer to clearness than precision.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, 은혜 is grace as in *grace of God*.  It generally means a huge favor or act of kindness, by someone much higher than you (say, a god or a king).

It does *not* mean grace as in *a graceful motion*, so that part might be a mistranslation, unless you're going to a Christian Taekwondo school.  :P